# Modular Scale line-heights

Tags: css, text, scale, typography

I'm current trying out the different methods to structure web elements and text, you know baseline grids, modular scale or both combined to see what is the best. I'm currently trying out modular scale just now.

I was wondering how I would go about calculating line-height for header tags using the following scale?

http://www.modularscale.com/?16,80&px&1.618&web&table

I know the very basic idea is to pick a number from the first column as the text size and a number for the middle column for the line-height.

let's say we use 67.773px for an H1 tag, what line-height would I give that? Using 4.236em from the middle column as its line-height doesn't look great at all.

I'm probably missing something really obvious here...

Thanks.

Comment: The combination you reference is not one of font-size/line-height. 67.773px is **equal to** 4.236em if using 16px as a base-font-size (which then would be 1em). Usually, you only define line-height once in `em`, like for example `body { line-height: 1.5em; }`, according to your visual preferences.

Comment: `line-height: 1.5` works better since it's a ratio